# Sharing the Build Queue defined variables in Release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can we use the Build pipeline Queue defined variables in Release pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and share the variable group between your builds and releases.

Comment: Or Martin Hinshelwood's tasks to save and rehydrate the variables between stages: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.variablehydration

Comment: this is interesting, i didnt know you can link variable group to the build definition, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Assuming on your build pipeline you've created variable like `PipelineVariable` and either assigned a default value or assigned one at queue time.  Assume you set the parameter value to `Testing`

In your release pipeline, you can use the [Builds API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get the queue-time parameters.  You can make them available using an inline powershell script calling the API and using the [setvariable](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) command to save a release variable.  You might want to use this as opposed to Variable Groups if you are entering queue time variables.

```
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)"

$buildParameters = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer 
$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" } -Method Get |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty parameters | 
    ConvertFrom-Json

$buildParameters |
    Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
    ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$_]$($buildParameters.$_)"
    }
```

Now in following phases you can reference that value.  For example, if you created an inline powershell script to print the value:

```
Write-Host "$env:PIPELINEVARIABLE"
```

**Returns:**

> Testing

Comment: If you're going to downvote my answer, I'd appreciate at least a reasoning.